# Android PendingIntent extras are updated, how to prevent?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I implemented GCM client in my application by using this: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

But in my `GcmIntentService` I want to send 2 notifications with different extras.
In first notification I set `notif1` extra to `true`, I don't set `notif2` extra.
In second notification I set `notif2` extra to `true`, I don't set `notif1` extra.

But when I click notification and check for its extra data, I see that both first and second PendingIntents have same extra data.

Regarding to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#constants) `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` causes this behaviour. So I changed it to `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` and `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`. But in this case earlier notifications' PendingIntents are cancelled.

So how can I send 2 notifications from `GcmIntentService` by using different extra data ?

Minimum service code is like this:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    Context mContext;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        mContext = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (extras != null) {
            if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
                if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

                    // first notification
                    Map<String, Boolean> pExtrasMap1 = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                    pExtrasMap1.put("notif1", true);
                    sendNotification(mContext, "My Title 1", "Hello 1..", pExtrasMap1);

                    // second notification
                    Map<String, Boolean> pExtrasMap2 = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                    pExtrasMap2.put("notif2", true);
                    sendNotification(mContext, "My Title 2", "Hello 2..", pExtrasMap2);

                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void sendNotification(Context pContext, String pTitle, String pText, Map<String, Boolean> pExtras) {
        Integer notifId = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100000 - 1) + 1));

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(pContext)
                        .setContentTitle(pTitle)
                        .setContentText(pText)
                ;
        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(pContext, MyPrettyActivity.class);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : pExtras.entrySet())
        {
            targetIntent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(pContext, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(pContext, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(pContext, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(notifId, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: use different requestCodes

Answer (score 1):

As user pskink noted in a comment on another answer, you need to use different request codes. PendingIntents aren't actually stored uniquely per object on the Android Framework side, they are hashed on just a few pieces of the PendingIntent and stored that way. If you have two PendingIntents that are the same in those particular pieces, the framework considers them to be the same.

> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the  same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,  expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by `Intent.filterEquals`. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per `Intent.filterEquals`, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
>
> There are two typical ways to deal with this.
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by `Intent.filterEquals`, or different request code integers supplied to `getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int)`, `getActivities(Context, int, Intent[], int)`, `getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int)`, or `getService(Context, int, Intent, int)`.

The way I get around this in my GCM implementation is to assign a random integer for the requestCode for each PendingIntent.

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation (as quoted below) both notifications would have the same ID, and therefore the second notification would replace the first. You should use unique IDs if you want to see both.

```
public static void sendNotification(Context pContext, String pTitle, String pText, Map<String, Boolean> pExtras) 
{
     Integer notifId=1;
    ...
     nManager.notify(notifId, builder.build());
}
```

In addition, as pskink suggested, try to use different request code for the two notifications (that's the `0` parameter below) :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    pContext, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: I fixed that id with random number and edited question. But this doesn't solve PendingIntent issue.

Comment: use different requestCodes

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. so I used `setAction()` to overcome this because I only neened to pass a single value and using **ACTION** did the trick.